# Send json object using POST pure javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to send a `JSON object` to `PHP` server but I get an empty array there. Why is this happening?

```
var obj = {
    username: username,
    password: password
};

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('post', 'ajax/login_register.php');
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
ajax.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: That is how you do it. The problem must be with how you are reading the data.

Comment: `$_POST` ?   @Quentin

Comment: That would be it. JSON requests don't populate `$_POST`. See the duplicate question.

Comment: try setting the request header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than `application/json;charset=UTF-8` ;-)

Comment: @RamRaider — The data in the question is encoded as JSON, it doesn't use form encoding.

Comment: try and you will see...

Comment: @Quentin I agree this probably has a duplicate somewhere but does that one really match? OP is asking how to send it, not receive it.

Comment: @MikeC — The code in the question is correct for sending it. The OP's comment shows that the problem *was* with how they were trying to recieve it.

Comment: @Quentin My mistake. Guess that's what I get for not working with raw XMLHttpRequest's in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give it a name that you can reference on the server side.

```
ajax.send('user=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

---

```
$_POST['user'] // <-- your JSON string
```

Comment: I have tried this way and works but how` jQuery` does it so we do not use `$_POST['user']` in the back-end?

Comment: This won't send a JSON request. It will send a (badly because you forgot to use `encodeURIComponent`) form encoded request with a JSON text embedded in it.

Comment: Do you mean you can access the individual properties through `$_POST`? That's done by extracting each property and sending it as a separate property.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I want. You mean `ajax.send('username=username&pass=pass');` like this ?

Comment: @rexhin Yup, that would work.

Comment: so this is the only way to read it from `$_POST` ?

Comment: @rexhin Pretty much. Every value has to have a matching name. It's up to you how to divvy that up.

Comment: won't work if OP keeps using contentType application/json

Comment: Hey work perfect for me! thanks!